# DynamoDBMapper batchLoad pass in parameters

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

There are two ways for DDBMapper to call batchLoad, differing in different pass-in parameters.

```
public Map<String,List<Object>> batchLoad(Iterable<? extends Object> itemsToGet)

public Map<String,List<Object>> batchLoad(Map<Class<?>,List<KeyPair>> itemsToGet)
```

I understand the second way, which makes more sense to me by specifying keyPair.
Then what about the first one? So basically just to pass in a list? Then whats the difference? The second one obviously looks more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine I have a User object with partition key userId and range key createdDate. I want to batch load 3 Users.

In the second option I have to create 3 key-pairs of userId and createdDate. In the first option I instantiate 3 User objects using userId and createdDate and put them in a List.

The first option might be more appropriate if I have logic in the User constructor. For example maybe createdDate cannot be more than 1 year ago. In this case creating User objects is an advantage as the constructor logic is executed. Alternatively I may have been passed the User object from some other part of the application, in which case creating key-pairs from them is just extra code I shouldn't need to write.

So basically there isn't much difference. I suspect some people will find the first option more pleasing since DynamoDBMapper is an object persistence solution, so it should support passing objects (not undefined key-pairs) around.

Comment: What if you don't know how many items it will return? (For example, one user with multiple game scores). Are you limited to using option 2?